# I2C in Master mode Reading 2 bytes from LIDAR SF20

Tags: interrupt, i2c, stm32f4, lidar

I have STM32F103 microcontroller and I want to interface it with LIDAR using I2C bus in Interrupt mode. It's working fine in Polling mode.

Problems i have faced is:
-- Bus has not been released after reading 2 bytes.

can some one explain me that how to read 2 bytes from I2C bus in STM32F103?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to initialize the I2C bus.

```
/* I2C1 init function */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 400000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

Then, you can read 2 bytes with calling `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read`.

```
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1,(uint16_t)(ADDRESS << 1),register_address,I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT,rxbuffer,buffer_size,100);
```